# laravel 5.1 it's Call to a member function where() on string

Tags: php, laravel-5

i am used laravel 5.1

i try to solved

**model**

```
 public function scopeLoacatedAt($zip, $street, $query)
    {
        return $query->where(compact('zip','street'));
          $street = str_replace('-',' ', $street);   
    }
```

**controller function**

```
 public function show($zip, $street)
    {    
        $flyer =  Flyer::loacatedAt($zip, $street)->first();    
        return view('flyers.show', compact('flyer'));
    }
```

Error message when i run in browser
    i deleted compact 
and use another elquent collection i have same msg
     Call to a member function where() on string

Comment: it's url http://localhost:8000/flyers/54870-7260/70036%20Freddie%20Roads

Comment: your localhost is not accesable with us. Please explain your problem, that what your requirement and what you want ?

Comment: want to display a page containing data according to zip and street ..... such this  localhost:8000/flyers/54870-7260/70036%20Freddie%20Roads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$query` need to be the first parameter.

It should be:

```
public function scopeLoacatedAt($query, $zip, $street)
{
    $street = str_replace('-',' ', $street);   
    return $query->where(compact('zip','street'));
}
```